# Is there a way to get the info from which makefile target is being running

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have huge code base that includes huge number of makefiles. I am trying to understand the flow. For that i am running make command with debug flags (`--debug=basic`) to get the information like what is the order of targets being executed.

build command:- `make --debug=basic release`

Here is the debug info:-

```
File 'release' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'release'.
    File 'all' does not exist.
       File 'copy_exports_files' does not exist.
         File '/test/sw/modules/bin/ctk' does not exist.
        Must remake target '/test/sw/modules/bin/ctk'
        ...
```

I can see flow of the targets being triggered. But I want to understand from which makefile the target is being triggered. Is there a way to log that info? Because its been hard to find where one makefile include other and soo on.

Thanks!

Comment: Flag `-d` adds a lot of information, for example `make -d someTarget`

Comment: Yes it adds lot of information which is going to be huge log that i wanted to avoid. I am looking for the information where running `<target>` is from particular `make`  file. Do we have any such debug flags to show that info?

Comment: See answer below

Comment: `make -f <makefile> --debug=verbose <target>`

Answer (score 1):

Try `make --debug=verbose release`